# how to fix repair yum on redhat vm

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos, yum

I have a VM hosted on Bluehost. I am having trouble installing Xvfb with yum. Anything I try with yum (`$ yum`, `$ yum install Xvfb`, etc) gives the following error;

`CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf`

Using PuTTY to login to my site, if I type `rpm -qi yum` I get

```
me@mysite.com [~]# rpm -qi yum
Name        : yum                          Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 3.2.29                            Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 43.el6.centos                 Build Date: Tue Dec 17 05:27:10 2013
Install Date: Wed Jan  8 02:21:22 2014         Build Host: c6b9.bsys.dev.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Base       Source RPM: yum-3.2.29-43.el6.centos.src.rpm
Size        : 4736145                          License: GPLv2+
Signature   : RSA/SHA1, Tue Dec 17 06:24:32 2013, Key ID --8bytesOfHex--
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
URL         : http://yum.baseurl.org/
Summary     : RPM package installer/updater/manager
Description :
Yum is a utility that can check for and automatically download and
install updated RPM packages. Dependencies are obtained and downloaded
automatically, prompting the user for permission as necessary.
```

I do not even know where this package is located so that I can give the contents of `yum.conf`

Comment: What does `rpm -qf /etc/yum.conf` say?

Comment: @SamiLaine the output of that is `yum-3.2.29-43.el6.centos.noarch`